# Extending Issued ERC 20 Token

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment

I have already issued my ERC 20 token. But I want to add a time locking functionality to the token so the tokens issued during pre-sale / ICO will be time locked in user's wallets.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add functionality to your token after it has been deployed (unless you saw this problem in advance and added some way of extending the functionality).

So basically you can only use the functionality your token has built-in. If there is no such time lock, then you can't use time lock and you can't prevent your users from transferring tokens.

Comment: Thanks Lauri. Is it possible to create another ERC 20 with same symbol name? If not can you tell me which framework is good for creating time locked contract and other features? https://openzeppelin.org/?

Comment: You can create a new contract with exactly the same details. The symbol and name are just for visualization purposes - there are probably tons of conflicts in those around different tokens.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot! You have to modify the code the deploy another smart contract. There's some ways to make a upgradeable smart contract but you have to do it from the first time.